# What synchronizer to use for thread initialization?

Tags: java, multithreading

What is the best synchronizer we can use to initialize thread before we start utilizing it?

```
public class Worker extends Thread {

    private volatile boolean isAlive;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        isAlive = true;
        try {
            do {
                //doSomething
            } while (true);
        } finally {
            isAlive = false;
        }
    }

    public void waitForSomething() {
        if (!isAlive) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Worker is not alive");
        }
        //something
    }

    public void waitForStartOfDoingSomething() {
        //need to wait isAlive = true.
    }
}
```

At the moment the code above does not guarantee that method `waitForSomething` will not throw `IllegalStateException` in the next case:

```
Worker worker = new Worker();
worker.start();
worker.waitForStartOfDoingSomething();
worker.waitForSomething();
//Then we let plenty of others threads to call worker.waitForSomething
```

I want to guarantee that `worker.waitForSomething()` in the case above will never throw `IllegalStateException`

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you need to achieve? What is your usecase?

Comment: do you want to make other threads wait until worker thread done it's work?

Comment: @HadiMoloodi, no, I want a guarantee that `waitForSomething()` will never throw `IllegalStateException` in the case I described

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to check [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) for this purpose.

```
private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

public void run() {
  try {
    do {
      //doSomething
    } while (true);
  } finally {
    latch.countDown();
  }
}

public void waitForSomething() throws InterruptedException {
  latch.await();
  //something
}
```

Comment: Thanks, forgot what it's called.

Comment: isAlive must be true when we call waitForSomething but in your code waitForSomething start running when isActive=false;

Comment: @HadiMoloodi `isActive` will never be `true` when the original `Runnable` finishes. The entire code is not really reasonable.

Comment: @daniu it is just a synthetic example

Comment: @AleksandrSemyannikov Well this solution (the one you marked as "correct") will trigger the "something" in `waitForSomething()` when the `isAlive` in your original code becomes `false`. It was my guess that's what you meant, but people having to guess is not a good thing if you expect a good answer.

Comment: @daniu, thank you for your comment, I've edited the code in the answer

Comment: @EyalSchneider, thanks for your answer, could you, please, approve my edit to keep your answer completely pertinent to the question?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you call waitForSomething method, run method from Worker did not called yet. you should make some time before calling waitForSomething. something like this

```
public class Worker extends Thread {

    private volatile boolean isAlive;
    private Semaphore sema = new Semaphore(1);

    public Worker() {
        try {
            sema.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        isAlive = true;
        sema.release();
        try {
            do {
                //doSomething
            } while (true);
        } finally {
            isAlive = false;
        }
    }

    public void waitForSomething() {
        try {
            sema.acquire();
            if (!isAlive) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Worker is not alive");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            sema.release();
        }
        //something
    }

    public void waitForStartOfDoingSomething() {
        //need to wait isAlive = true.
    }
}
```

another workaround which I'm not a fan of, would be to change your scenario

```
Worker worker = new Worker();
worker.start();
Thread.sleep(500);
worker.waitForStartOfDoingSomething();
worker.waitForSomething();
```

But if I know more about your program I could be more helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `CompletableFuture`.

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    do {
        //doSomething
    } while (true);
}).thenRunAsync(
    // do something more
);
```

"something more" will not run if an exception occurs in `stageOne`.